# APACHE Mod Rewrite - Dynamic URLs to Semantic URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic-url

I have a little web app based on Google Maps. I have URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/web.php?u=olives-restaurante-de-ensaladas-en-margarita
```

and I want to have exactly this:

```
http://www.example.com/web/olives-restaurante-de-ensaladas-en-margarita
```

So I want to convert my parametric `dynamic URLs` into `semantic URLs`

How can I achieve this?!

I have tried to put the following code on my `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^web/([A-Z0-9]+)/$ web.php?u=$1
```

But sadly, when I try to access `http://www.example.com/web/olives-restaurante-de-ensaladas-en-margarita` it redirects me to 404 page.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please note that this question is SEO related in matter of `programming` following the guidelines.

Comment: Maybe my server don't accept Mod-Rewrite? How can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^web/([A-Z0-9]+)/$ web.php?u=$1
>
> http://www.ubikate.com.ve/web/olives-restaurante-de-ensaladas-en-margarita
> ```

Your `RewriteRule` *pattern* (`^web/([A-Z0-9]+)/$`) does not allow hyphens, enforces a trailing slash and only matches uppercase letters, so this won't match the URL you are requesting.

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^web/([\w-]+)$ web.php?u=$1 [L]
```

The `\w` is a shorthand character class that is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: Try temporarily changing this into a _redirect_: `RewriteRule ^web/([\w-]+)$ /web.php?u=$1 [R,L]` (note the slash prefix and the `R` flag). What do you see in the browsers address bar?

Comment: Did it, I see the same: `http://www.example.com/web/olives-restaurante-de-ensaladas-en-margarita/`

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Or any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: No, that's the only one, located at `/public_html/` and I have only 3 lines: `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^web/([\w-]+)$ /web.php?u=$1 [R,L]
`

Comment: Just try adding some "nonsense" at the top of the file. Do you get an error? (You should get a 500 error.)

Comment: WOW! this is odd! I don't get the 500 error, I have downloaded with FileZilla the file and it have NOT the changes, there some like `cache` on the server, how can I clean it?

Comment: I have tried your code in my localhost and it works! but all the CSS and images are messed up :(

Comment: Not sure about the "cached file" on your server?! How were you editing the file? Ordinarily, if you didn't get an error, it would indicate that `.htaccess` files are not enabled (you would need `AllowOverride All` - or similar in the server config). If the CSS and images are "messed up", it suggests you are using _relative_ URLs - which will be a problem if you change the URL structure. See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737411/404-not-found-broken-links-to-css-images

Comment: Thanks, I think you really solve the problem, now I have another issues, I will mark this has the answer, thanks!