# Dynamic URL rewriting in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've a url like :

```
http://localhost/project/gallery_detail.php?id=3
```

what I want here is :

```
http://localhost/project/USERNAME/3
```

What I'm trying is :

```
RewriteEngine 
OnRewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ gallery_detail.php?id=$1
```

and handling this to php file but didn't succeed.

Comment: Try removing the leading slash **/** from your rule's pattern.

Comment: @starkeen trailing as well

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ gallery_detail.php?id=$1
> ```

In per-directory `.htaccess` files, the URL-path never starts with a slash. You are also only capturing 2 groups, when you need 3 and are using the first (ie. `project`) in the *substitution*.

Try something like the following instead, if your `.htaccess` file is located in the document root (ie. `localhost/.htaccess`).

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/[^/]+/(\d+)$ $1/gallery_detail.php?id=$2 [L]
```

You don't need to capture groups if you don't need them. `[^/]+` is for 1 or more characters, other than slash (the directory separator).

**UPDATE:** However, if the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/project` subdirectory then change this to:

```
RewriteRule [^/]+/(\d+)$ gallery_detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: right, now what I'm trying to do here is I've generated my url like : 

http://localhost/project/USERNAME/3

now I want to redirect this to gallery_detail.php how can I do that any suggestion please

Comment: Yes, I've just updated my answer. However, this assumes your `.htaccess` file is located in the document root, ie. at `localhost/.htaccess`.

Comment: that is located under root directory of project e.g. localhost/project/.htaccess

Comment: RewriteRule ([^/]+)/[^/]+/(\d+)$ /$1/gallery_detail.php?id=$2 [L]

this is not working it is redirecting to localhost/xampp

Comment: I've just updated my answer for when the `.htaccess` is located at `/project/.htaccess`. This shouldn't be triggering an external redirect. Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Nope I don't have any other directory in .htaccess file and after putting this :
RewriteRule [^/]+/(\d+)$ gallery_detail.php?id=$2 [L] 

it is giving Object Not Found !!!

Comment: Sorry, that should be `$1`, not `$2` (copied from earlier rule).

Comment: one more thing its redirecting to gallery_detail.php page but the rule infected the CSS and JS also how can we exclude those ???

Comment: like 
http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/USERNAME/js/additional-methods.min.js

so how can we exclude this ?

Comment: That will happen if you are using relative paths to your CSS and JS files. You should use root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute (scheme+hostname+path) or use the `base` tag as a workaround. See my answer to this other question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43737573/369434

Comment: I'm having one more prob here I was configuring this to server now the URL is like :

http://localhost/project/master/USERNAME/3

in this case that rule was not working any suggestion ?

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` file still at `/project/.htaccess`?