# PHP Local CMS CSS Error

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am creating a local CMS. Any link to the website redirects to index.php through `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cms/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

In the `index.php` file, the URL gets controlled. If the path begins with *admin* then `admin.main.php` gets included.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
    $request_url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

    while (substr($request_url, -1) == '/') {
        $request_url = rtrim($request_url, '/');
    }

    $explode_url = explode('/', $request_url);
    if (isset($explode_url[1]) && $explode_url[1] == 'admin') {
        require('includes/admin/admin.main.php');
    }
}
```

The `admin.main.php` controlls if request is `/admin/pages`, and if so another file gets included.

```
global $request_url;

if ($request_url == '/admin/pages') {
    require('includes/admin/panel/panel.pages.php');
}
```

In the head of `panel.pages.php` a link to the CSS-file is included with the path `includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css`. The problem is that if you go to `http://localhost/cms/admin/pages` the HTML and PHP code runs, but not the CSS or the JS (which is included in the bottom). In the Chrome Developer Tool, the href of the link to the CSS is `http://localhost/cms/admin/pages/includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css`.

To mention is also that `../` can be done multiple times before the href, but with the same result and link. In the CMS-directory (base), there is no directory with the name *admin*, the directory to admin-folder is `includes/admin`.

Comment: Make the script calls absolute, start with a `/` so it goes to the base of your server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [404 not found - broken links to CSS, images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737411/404-not-found-broken-links-to-css-images)

Comment: The problem with using absolute requests, starting with a `/`, is that if you have the website inside a folder on a domain or localhost, this base directory will not be included. For example: the href of the script and stylesheet becomes http://localhost/includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css, which returns an error since the path shall be http://localhost/cms/includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css. @chris85 @MrWhite