# 404 not found - CSS and JS when url ends with /

Tags: php, html, css

This question regards the same CMS and files provided in my previous question: [PHP Local CMS CSS Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004307/php-local-cms-css-error).

I am very confused at the moment. If I visit http://localhost/cms/admin the CSS and JS get executed perfectly, with the href (CSS) http://localhost/cms/includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css. However, as I visit http://localhost/cms/admin/ (with a `/` added to the end), the href instead becomes http://localhost/cms/admin/includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css.

Any link to the website redirects to index.php through .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cms/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

In the index.php file, the URL gets controlled. If the path begins with admin then admin.main.php gets included.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
    $request_url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

    while (substr($request_url, -1) == '/') {
        $request_url = rtrim($request_url, '/');
    }

    $explode_url = explode('/', $request_url);
    if (isset($explode_url[1]) && $explode_url[1] == 'admin') {
        require('includes/admin/admin.main.php');
    }
}
```

The admin.main.php controls if request is /admin/pages, and if so another file gets included.

```
global $request_url;

if ($request_url == '/admin/pages') {
    require('includes/admin/panel/panel.pages.php');
}
```

In the head of panel.pages.php:

```
<?php
echo <link rel='stylsheet' type='text/css' href='includes/assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf');
echo <link rel='stylsheet' type='text/css' href='includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css'>
?>
```

**EDIT:** I am not entirely upset with this solution, if you have a suggestion on another method, please share.

Comment: You can use [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved the problem by a combination of your solutions and google. To use absolute path was a good option, but as the CMS must be compatible with all sorts of folders and website directory structures, I had to change that solution a little. In the begging of the index.php (which includes every other file), I added:

```
$base = rtrim(rtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 'index.php');
```

Which in my case returns `/cms/`.

In the panel.pages.php, which gets included, the `href` and `src` then use an absolute path starting with the `$base` variable. This makes it compatible with any website structure.

Please correct me if I am wrong with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing in your html you have:

```
<link href="../includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css">
```

So when you are here: `http://localhost/cms/admin`

the `..` tells it to go up one level (to `http://localhost/cms/`) and then add `includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css`, giving you `http://localhost/cms/includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css`.

When you are here: `http://localhost/cms/admin/`, it treats it as if you were at something like `http://localhost/cms/admin/index`

the `..` tells it to go up one level (to `http://localhost/cms/admin/`) and then add `includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css`, giving you `http://localhost/cms/admin/includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css`.

Best practice (IMO) is to not use (fully?) relative paths - your CSS `href` should always start with a `/` so that it is relative to the document root.

```
<link href="/cms/includes/admin/CSS/panel.pages.css">
```

Comment: But the directory for the file may not always be /cms/. The CMS must be compatible with all sorts of websites and directories.