# NextJS htaccess setup without a trailing slash on URLs

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Found a problem with my site on NextJS. During development, I navigated the site using buttons and manually changing the browser address bar. It happened that I accidentally added a slash to the end, but my localhost server removed it and everything worked fine.

But everything changed when I uploaded my static application to the hosting. It automatically began to add these slashes when reloading the page. Because of this, my pictures on the site break.

As far as I understand, you need to correctly configure the `.htaccess` file.

Here is what it looks like now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your existing `.htaccess` rules are all expecting a trailing slash. So, to clarify, the canonical URL does *not* have a trailing slash? You only have URLs of the form `/foo` and `/foo/bar`?

Comment: (Where did these rules come from to begin with? "but my localhost server removed it" - How?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, there shouldn't be a trailing slash at the end.

Comment: When I said that the localhost removes the slash, I meant the default option in the next js config called skipTrailingSlashRedirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
> RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
> ```

Your existing rules are all expecting (or forcing) a trailing slash on all your URLs. So, if the canonical URL (and the URL you are linking to) does not include a trailing slash then all these rules essentially need to be reversed. However, there are other issues here (the first rule, for instance, is *unconditionally* rewriting the request to append the `.html` extension, which is repeated in the next rule *with* a condition.)

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# (OPTIONAL) Remove trailing slash if it happens to be on the request
# Exclude physical directories (which must end in a slash)
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite request to corresponding ".html" file if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

Your original directives only handled URLs with one or two path depth (eg. `/foo/` or `/foo/bar/`). The second rule above handles any path depth (if so required). eg. `/foo`, `/foo/bar`, `/foo/bar/baz` etc. (no trailing slash).

As an optimisation I've *assumed* your URLs that require rewriting do not contain dots (that are otherwise used to delimit the file extension).

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) matches against the URL-path only (not the query string). If there is any query string on the initial request then this is simply passed through by default. (With regards to the rewrite and client-side JS, the query string is available on the initial request and should be parsed as before.)

> Because of this, my pictures on the site break.

This will happen if you are using relative URLs to your images. You should really be using root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute URLs to resolve this issue. See also:

- [404 not found - broken links to CSS, images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737411/404-not-found-broken-links-to-css-images)

Comment: Amazing! It works perfectly! But what if I have a page with search parameters, for example:

localhost:3000/watch?video=some-id/  ->  localhost:3000/watch?video=some-id

Comment: @FORCH That should be handled without issue. `/watch?video=some-id/` would be internally rewritten to `/watch.html?video=some-id/` - trailing slash intact. (The query string is simply passed through, but this is available on the initial request to client-side JS). The trailing slash is only removed on the URL-path. So, `/watch/?video=xyz` is redirected to `/watch?video=xyz`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Maybe you know some method to enable dynamic routing with htaccess? Now I have watch.html and watch/[id].html files but it making 404 error after reloading